# scp from Amazon ec2 is hanging, but SSH works fine

Tags: amazon-ec2, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from an ec2 instance to my local machine. Here's the command:

```
scp -v -i commoncrawl_practice.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-86-8-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/testfile .
```

And here's where it hangs:

```
debug1: Trying private key: commoncrawl_practice.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ec2-54-86-8-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com ([54.86.8.91]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /home/ec2-user/testfile
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you ssh to the machine ? `scp` uses `ssh` as a transport protocol.

Comment: Yes, see the title. SSH works fine.

Comment: Try copying to a different directory, other than `/home/ec2-user/testfile`

Comment: No, that didn't work. Still hanging.

Comment: You can try from a different client, try to narrow down if the problem is with the server or the client.

Comment: Same issue... any results?

Comment: I had the same problem. Also, dns lookup wasn't working for me. ping www.google.com didn't work but ping to google servers ip worked. Reason still unkown. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102049

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a ~/.bashrc file on the destination which prints stuff to your terminal. If yes, disable it for non-interactive shells by inserting

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return
```

before printing anything.

(solution found on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/scp-fails-without-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try SFTP as an alternative to SCP.